# Polarization and electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

First of all I need to know what is polarization, does it completely restricts the vibration of an field (in light waves) out it justs reduces the amplitude of the vibration
Second, If polarization completely restricts an field ,let's assume it restricts electric field. Then will that plane polarized light still be electromagnetic or will it change it's properties, because in electromagnetic wave there are both fields (electric and magnetic) mutually perpendicular to each other as well as to the direction of propagation of wave
I have more questions but they are related to these questions or let's say depend on these

Answer (score 1):

Polarization refers to the direction of oscillation of the electric field in an electromagnetic wave (and because the magnetic field is always perpendicular to the electric field, polarization also determines the direction of oscillation of the magnetic field).

In linearly polarized light, the electric field oscillates along a line (and the magnetic field oscillates along a line perpendicular to it, and perpendicular to the direction of propagation of the wave).

It's still an electromagnetic wave, with the fields perpendicular to each other and to the direction of propagation.

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding on polarization, you should consider reading the wikipedia-article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(waves)

But to your questions:

-Polarization describes the orientation of a wave, not its amplitude.

-"Linear polarization" or "plane polarization" states a certain phase-correlation between (in this case) the electric and the magnetic field.
In this case, the phases between both fields are equal.